# how can I make a $(document).ready using coffeescript to call my functions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to find a way to "call" my functions, for example, I have this function

```
initSlider = ($element)->
 $element.find('.slider').each ->
   $this.slider
   ... some functions
```

that prints on my web this

```
 initSlider();
  root = typeof exports !== "undefined" && exports !== null ? exports : this;
  root.foo = function() {
  return function($element) {
  $element.find('.slider').each(function() {
   $this = $(this);
   $this.slider({ 
   ... and so on
```

and what I basically want to do its something like initSlider() so, the function can be executed... I tried just like that initSlider() on my file, but does nothing...

Thanks

Comment: I read the question 4 times, still have no idea what you are trying to say. Could you please rephrase the question? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

`$ -> initSlider()`

would result in
`$(function(){ initSlider() })`

that, of course, presume that initSlider is in the global scope

another option is doing something like

```
initSlider = ($elm) -> 
   // your code indented 

$ -> initSlider($elm)
```